# How can I make an interactive menu with C?

Tags: c

For some reason my program will print the menu (with the ShowMenu function) and then just end the program. I tried debbuging but no problem appeared.

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    bool Again = true;
    char* MenuName = "Games";
    char* MenuOptions[] = {"Tetris", "Paintball", "Wakfu", "Dofus", "Pokemon", "Legend of Zelda", "Super Mario bros", "Metroman"};
    int MenuSize = sizeof(MenuOptions);
    int Input = MenuSize + 1;
    printf("This program will show an interactive menu\n"); //What it does
    ShowMenu(MenuName, MenuOptions, MenuSize, Again, Input);
    return 0;
}

void ShowMenu(char* MenuName, char* MenuOptions[], int MenuSize, bool Again, int Input){
    while (Again){
        printf("%s\n", MenuName);
        for (int i = 0; i < MenuSize; i++){
            printf("%d - %s\n", i, MenuOptions[i]);
        }
        MenuSelection(Input, MenuOptions, MenuSize, Again);
    }
}

void MenuSelection (int Input, char* MenuOptions[], int MenuSize, bool Again){
    printf("Please choose an option within the menu\n");
    scanf("%d", &Input);
    if (Input > 0 && Input < MenuSize){
        return printf("%s\n", MenuOptions[Input]);
        Again = false;
    }
}```
````

Comment: `return printf("%s\n", MenuOptions[Input]);` What is the return value of `printf` ?

Comment: ^^^^ equally perplexing, how do you expect the `Again = false;` that follows to ever be executed with a hard, unconditional `return` on the line-prior, and even if it were, to ever actually mean anything in the context of the callers code?

Comment: Are you expecting the changes you do to  `Again` in `MenuSelection` be reflected in `ShowMenu` ?

Comment: Well, yes, I want to use the bool Again to so it isn't stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: But your current code wont stop after your first choice, it will repeatedly ask for you to enter, is it not? put a `printf` after the `MenuSelection` call and  inside `MenuSelection` after `Again = false;` and check. If you want to stop when `Again` is set to false you will have to pass address of `Again`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calculating the `MenuSize` correctly, print the `MenuSize` after your statement and see for yourself and `printf` returns the number of characters printed, so `return printf("%s\n", MenuOptions[Input]);` is not useful for you in anyway for your purpose.

This will cover most of your question, if you change below

`int MenuSize = sizeof(MenuOptions);`

to

`int MenuSize = sizeof(MenuOptions) /  sizeof(MenuOptions[0]);`

and

`return printf("%s\n", MenuOptions[Input]);`

to

`printf("%s\n", MenuOptions[Input]);`